# Remove all url parameter in file:///

Tags: html, cordova, url, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a Cordova App, and I use a URL parameter to manipulate or control my pages. e.g.:

```
file:///App/www/index.html?goto=profile
```

What I am trying to do is to remove the `goto` parameter from the URL.

An example use case: the user login using a temporary password. When the user logged in successfully the app will point them to the "change password" page, which is represented by a parameter on the url - `?goto=profile`. Now the url has this parameter.

The problem here is that two parameters are set; `?goto=profile` and `?goto=messages` (directed the user on his inbox page). So the url now would be `file:///App/www/index.html?goto=profile?goto=messages`.

How to remove the `?goto=profile` in the url without reloading the page?

Comment: please provide more context - why do you want to remove that part of the url? what are you trying to achieve? what is the specific problem you're facing? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @EliranMalka added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

to add multiple search query parameters, concatenate them with an ampersand (`&`). e.g.:

```
file:///App/www/index.html?goto=profile&goto=messages
```

if you don't want multiple parameters (they have the same name, so i presume you only want to replace the `goto` parameter value), just overwrite it.

i don't know the implementation used for routing, as you did not specify it in your question, but with plain javascript, it'd be something like this:

```js
location.search = 'goto=messages';
```

Comment: One problem here is when I pressed the back button the parameter will again appear (bec. of history list). Is it possible to clear or remove it?

Comment: again, i don't know what is the router implementation used, so i have no knowledge of what's going on in your app, and what happens when the back button is pressed. provide more details, please; what frameworks/libraries are in use? show the code that's in charge of the routing